# If $4xy+3=c^2+3d^2$, is $xy$ necessarily a square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I have a polynomial which, simplified, ends up in the form
$$4xy+3 = c^2+3d^2.$$

Evidently $4xy+3$ is of the form $a^2+3b^2$, in light of the equality. But does
$$
    c^2 + 3d^2 = 4xy + 3 = xy(2)^2 + 3(1)^2
$$
necessarily force $xy$ to be a square? I just can't see how to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: No, $xy$ doesn't have to be a square. For example, if $c=2$, $d=3$, then $xy=\frac{4+27-3}{4}=\frac{28}{4}=7$. Thus the equality at hand does not imply that $xy$ is a square of some integer.

Comment: Well, that definitely answers that question!  =)

Comment: @Tomas: Please make your comment into an answer, so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just to remove this post from the Unanswered queue. As per the counterexample given by @Tomas, the answer is negative: $xy$ does **not** have to be a square.

Answer (score 0):

For the equation: $4xy+3=c^2+3d^2$

Can be written like such a simple solution:

$x=2a^2+6t^2-6at-2a+3t-1$

$y=2a^2+6t^2-6at-a+3t-1$

$c=2a^2+6t^2-6at-2$

$d=2a^2+6t^2-6at-2a+4t-1$

$a,t$ - what some integers any sign.